# Clear the current content from a Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I was wondering how you are meant to remove the current content from a frame and make it so it is not displaying anything? Also I would like to know how you are supposed to remove all the history from the frame as well?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

for removing the `Current Content`

```
frame1.Content = null;
```

for removing all `History` use `Navigated Event` and set

```
frame1.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To clean all History

```
while(frame1.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()!= null);
```